# Post an update to an asp.net core Razor page when the data model changes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm new to asp and web programming in general. I'm using Visual Studio 2017. I've created a Razor web application that uses an existing data model that I wrote for a Windows application. I'm able to display the values from my data model on my webpage when it first loads, but I can't figure out how to make the page show new values when they have changed in my data model. I'm used to working in WPF, binding to Dependency properties and INotifyPropertyChanged properties. Here is one of the property I am using for my Razor page:

```
    [BindProperty]
    public string VersionNumber { get; set; } = "0.0.0.0";
```

I've verified that the property is actually changing but the change is never reflected on the webpage.

I've tried it a couple of ways:

```
<form>
    <label style="margin: 5px;">
        Version
    </label>
    <input type="text" trim="false" uppercase="false" lowercase="false" propercase="false" asp-for="VersionNumber" />
</form>
```

and

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VersionNumber)
```

I realize I'm missing the concept of how this is supposed to work and hopefully the answer to this question will make the light bulb come on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to refresh the value in the browser whenever the value in the model changes - you mention INotifyPropertyChanged. I'm assuming you somehow trigger model changes with a timer or a schedule etc.

A website/page is rendered on the server and then displayed in browser. So to actually get a new value you need to somehow post the page back to the server, acquire a new value from model, render the page and display it in the browser.

For this you can use a button users clicks and queries the server for new data. If this is not something you want then perhaps you can check **SignalR** which is used to push changes to the client website rendered in the browser.

Comment: SignalR looks perfect for what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In short, to display text you should use the `@Html.DisplayFor(c=>c.VersionNumber)` helper. 
If you use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VersionNumber)` you say to Razor create a text input markup.
Look more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: I need the TextBox because the user needs to be able to change the Version Number. That's not the problem. My problem is that when the property is updated in the back-end data model, I don't know how to make the webpage show the updated value, no matter if it's a TextBox or not. I tried @Html.DisplayFor(c=>c.VersionNumber) and got the same results.

Comment: You can use simple input like  ` <input asp-for="VersionNumber" class="form-control" />` and if value if this field is not empty, Razor will be show it in the input. To show updated value, you need to refresh the page after updating, for example,after saving changes in your controller’s action return redirect to same action